# How to simulate AR(2) model in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand AR models but it's getting pretty difficult for me. Just wanted to ask you some hints on how to simulate an AR(2) model-driven by input as we wish (constant, coefficient, sd, for n values in R, without using any built function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop:

```
AR2.sim <- function(n, ar1, ar2, sd)
{
  Xt = c(0,0)
  for (i in 2:n)
  {
    Xt[i+1] = ar1*Xt[i] + ar2*Xt[i-1] + rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sd)
  }
  Xt
}
Xt = AR2.sim(100, 0.15, 0.73, 2)
plot(Xt, type = "o")
```

Here `n` is 100, the coefficients are 0.15 and 0.73, and standard error 2.[image]

Comment: Thank you, I modified the Xt[i+1] to be Xt[i] , makes the for(3:n) to make it more similar with the equation.